# CSS height relations between divs

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

First off I'd like to say that this HTML and CSS are both valid. Second, hi.

I am making a blog and I have this structure in mind:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to have everything in percentages but I am willing to compromise.

My wrapper is 100% off of my html and body.

```
html, body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

In the said wrapper I have a header which I want to be 10% of the total wrapper height, content that is to be 80% of the parent and a 5% footer. My real problem is the content div, which I want it to be 80% if there is less text and expand more if there is more text but I'd like the other elements to have the same height.

I tried various solution on different threads and website but nothing really works the way I want it to, I also tried asking in some irc channels but they didn't help me either.

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
border:2px solid black;
height:100%;
width:70%;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
}

.header {
border:2px solid yellow;
min-height:10%;
margin:0 0;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
display:block
}

.footer {
border:2px solid blue;
min-height:35px;
margin:0 0;
bottom:0;
position:relative;
}

.content {
min-height:auto;
border:2px solid green;
margin:0 0;
padding:0;
position:relative;
}

html, body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> Blog </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="content">
        <p>*insert big text here*</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The clearest way would be using javascript to calculate the preferred height. Btw `overflow:auto` is default, so you can remove it from your css.

Comment: Can you explain this more? If the content DIV has less text, it should be 80%, but if there's more text it should expand? So it can expand past 100% of the browser height or no? Are the header and footer going to be fixed position, or if there is a lot of content will you have to scroll to see the footer?

Comment: thanks, I will remove it. Is resizing with javascript the only way?

Comment: @Gavin there will be scrollable content and the footer will be at the bottom. The content DIV should have 80% height by default so that with the header and footer the make 100% and the page is full. The text in the content may expand the content and make it scrollable.

Comment: Let me see if I can put a fiddle together.

Comment: Is this all you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/MGRq8/

Comment: Just copy and paste the <p> with the Lorem Ipsum text a few times to see what happens with more content.

Comment: @Gavin it works well, it keeps all elements in place, but the wrapper doesn't expand to to the footer. http://imgur.com/tVIhbkQ

Comment: Oh ok. That's easy. Just make a wrapper that's 100% min-height. Right?

Comment: Yeah this is more difficult than I thought. Apparently this is newer behavior in browsers. I'm still thinking it's possible with just CSS though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this (but note that there will be a 5% not covered: 10% + 80% + 5% = 95%):

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper_positioner{
margin:0 auto;
width:70%;
}
.wrapper{
position:absolute;
width:70%;
height: 100%;
}
.header {
border:2px solid yellow;
margin:0 0;
height:10%;
}

.footer {
border:2px solid blue;
margin:0 0;
height:5%;
min-height: 35px;
}

.content {
border:2px solid green;
margin:0 0;
padding:0;
height: 80%;
}

html, body{
width:100%;
height: 100%;
height: auto;
margin:0px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> Blog </title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper_positioner">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="content">
            <p>*insert big text here*</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The content doesn't expand. The text overflows, I want the CONTENT DIV to contain it.

Comment: @EcoGiko i don't see how this solves the problem, the content will still overflow in this solution.! http://jsfiddle.net/X5MS8/9/

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make something else. I am taking the wrapper away, because it is really annoying and I am centring all my divs with margin:0, auto; I gave all divs width:70% and everything is working now. This is my **CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
border:2px solid black;
height:100%;
width:70%;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
}

.header {
border:2px solid yellow;
min-height:10%;
width:70%;
margin:0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
position:static;
display:block
}

.footer {
border:2px solid blue;
min-height:35px;
width:70%;
margin:0 auto;
bottom:0;
position:relative;
}

.content {
min-height:80%;
height:auto;
width:70%;
border:2px solid green;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
position:relative;
}

.navigation_bar {
font-size:20px;
border-spacing:70px 20px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
position:relative;
}

td {
padding:0;
}

html, body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
overflow:auto;
}

body {
background: url(Static/Index/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}

#wrapper_background{
background: url(Static/Index/content_background.png) no-repeat;
background-size:cover; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> Blog </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="content">
        <p>*insert big big big text here*</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am marking the closest answer to my problem as an answer. I think that my opinion on how it should be done shouldn't effect you answers. Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You've accepted an answer already, but if you're curious about doing it with JavaScript/jQuery, this is how you'd do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/MGRq8/2/

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var headerHeight = viewportHeight * 0.1;
var contentMinHeight = viewportHeight * 0.8;
var footerHeight = viewportHeight * 0.05;

$('#header').height(headerHeight);
$('#content').css('min-height', contentMinHeight);
$('#footer').height(footerHeight);

$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#wrapper").height($(document).height());
});
```

Comment: awesome, I'd love to know how to include that in my page.

Comment: Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9LKTk/. I would recommend changing your classes to IDs though.